# Update MAS Access Table

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

I have a VB6 application. The back end is MS Access. I have to execute a Update query. What is the easiest way to do so? I can not use the DOCmd option somehow. I dnt know the exact refernce needed to enable the DoCmd option. Can any one help me out.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it means, you have asked 20 questions, have never upvoted any answers or questions and accepted only 24% of the questions you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways of working with data in VB6 they are ADO and DAO. All things being equal, DAO will be relatively (though not necessarily absolutely) faster with JET. ADO gives you more functionality (full access to ACE's multi-valued types excepted) and offers an improved, flatter object model.

For this example we will use ADO. This is a sample of code that fires a delete command to delete a record with a given Message_ID

```
With adoFlash_delete_CMD
    .ActiveConnection = adoConnection
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblFlash_messages WHERE Message_ID=?"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, lMessage_ID)
End With

adoFlash_delete_CMD.Execute

Set adoFlash_delete_CMD = Nothing
```

You should be able to look at this example and tweak it for your needs.

Comment: I don’t have anything else to what Mr Fenton already posted to your post. If you feel that strongly about it then feel free to edit my answer if not then can we keep the discussion to solving the opening poster’s question and not semantics about 10 year old technology